# NServiceBus 5 to 7 upgrade - No Destination specified for message

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, nservicebus

I cannot seem to get NServiceBus working again after upgrading from NServiceBus 5 to 7.

I've uploaded my test solution to [github](https://github.com/Nick7b/NServiceBusTestClient/tree/master/NServiceBusTestClient).

The Error I'm getting right now is located in [Program.cs](https://github.com/Nick7b/NServiceBusTestClient/blob/master/NServiceBusTestClient/Program.cs) on line 95.
One level down it's on [NServiceBusHelper.cs](https://github.com/Nick7b/NServiceBusTestClient/blob/master/NServiceBusTestClient/NServiceBusHelper.cs) on line 29.

**The error states: "No destination specified for message: HyFlo.Service.Messages.Commands.Info.GetVersionCommand".**

We only use 1 EndpointConfiguration.

I've commented out the old (but working) NServiceBus 5.x code in [Program.cs](https://github.com/Nick7b/NServiceBusTestClient/blob/master/NServiceBusTestClient/Program.cs).

I hope someone can point me out on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have configured your routing: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/upgrades/6to7/#configuration-endpoint-mappings-command-routing

It looks like your routing configuration is commented out:

https://github.com/Nick7b/NServiceBusTestClient/blob/master/NServiceBusTestClient/Program.cs#L45-L48

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.
I tried that piece of code already but it isn't working, that's why it's commented out.
The problem now is that I AM receiving messages in the client, but it says; "System.INvalidOperationException: No handlers could be found for message type: Hyflo.Service.Messages.Commands.Info.GetVersionCommand".
This tells me it has something to do with https://github.com/Nick7b/NServiceBusTestClient/blob/master/NServiceBusTestClient/Program.cs#L88-L95

Comment: https://github.com/Nick7b/NServiceBusTestClient/blob/master/NServiceBusTestClient/NServiceBusHelper.cs should pick up the messages

Comment: I do not see an implementation of `IHandleMessages<GetVersionCommand>`. Do you have a handler for that message type?